# Can't index column after DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

After loading my data into a `DataGrid` using `WPF`:

```
    dataGrid1.DataContext = db.Select_Drawing_Numbers();
    dataGrid1.Columns[0].Width = 10;
```

But I get an error:

```
    Index is out of range. Please select a non-zero, non-negative integer.
```

How can I make sure the data is bound before calling `Columns[0]`?

Comment: It loads fine in the datagrid - all columns and data show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking into the [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event of the `DataGrid`. The issue you are having is that the `DataGrid` doesn't actually have any values loaded into it (and therefore has no columns/rows) until it is `Loaded`.